# Text on change queuing / backend database updating

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a JavaScript form that saves changes made to a `<textarea>` to my server via ajax call. I was hoping to keep thing simple and have wired up the `change` and `keyup` events and fire off calls to my server accordingly.

My issue occurs when multiple overlapping calls start causing optimistic concurrency issues with my database. (SQL 2008 with RowVersions).

1. Is there any way I can queue the ajax calls so I never have more than one going at a time?
2. Would a better approach be to use a timer instead of change events. Update every 2 seconds? Insure a final update `onBlur`?
3. Would this best be handled on the server since multiple clients (while unlikely) could still cause the same issue. What might that look like?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could reduce the number of calls is by delaying the ajax call for a few seconds to see if the user is going to keep typing. The body of your change/keyup listener would have something like this in it:

```
if(timeoutId){ 
    // prevent last timeout from sending the ajax call
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = 0;
}
timeoutId = setTimeout(sendAjaxToSaveState,delayInMilliseconds);
```

You should also send an ajax call on blur like you mentioned in your second option.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server should be able to handle update of a text field fast enough so that it would not lead to concurrency issues. I would advise you to use a profiler and figure out where exactly the latency is.

After doing that, if you still wish to queue your calls, I am not sure whether it could be done by queuing ajax, as ajax are handled in IIS worker processes in a multi-threaded environment.
Having said that, there is the option of implementing your own process queue, using singleton pattern.

In this case, you will create a static class in the application scope which will implement a command list. Your Ajax post handler will register the SQL command with the list and immediately exit. The class itself will process each command off the list in a serial fashion on a separate thread.

As you can see, you will have to do a bit of plumbing to get it working, so the best option may still be to figure why sql server (or any intermediate layer) is taking longer than it should to process the query.